# Обработка запроса Location в Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот, который обрабатывает запрос [`Location`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location) от пользователя. В случае, если на сервер приходит сообщение такого типа, бот может вернуть расстояние между координатами, которые пришли от пользователя и некой точкой на карте (`точка_А`).
Расширяем функционал: бот может вернуть расстояние до `точка_B` или `точка_А`. Вопрос: как серверу различать, расстояние до `A` или `B` хочет пользователь?

> Имею ввиду то, что прикрепляя геолокацию к сообщению, нельзя добавить текст или медиа к этому сообщению. Чистая локация и все. Если бы можно было отправить сообщение, которое содержало в себе два типа: `Location` и `Text`, было бы намного проще, - просто добавить строку `точка_А` к геолокации и все.

Можно ли сделать следующим способом?

- `msg_1`: пользователь отправляет сообщение типа `Text`: `"локация"`;
- `msg_2`: бот возвращает две кнопки: `точка_А` и `точка_B`;
- `msg_3`: пользователь выбирает нужную кнопку;
- `msg_4`: бот возвращает: `"отправь свое местонахождение"`;
- `msg_5`: пользователь отправляет `Location`;
- сервер считает расстояние;
- `msg_6`: бот возвращает расстояние.

Следующий вопрос: как получить данные `msg_3` на момент просчета расстояния, используя `Webhook`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) (встроенные кнопки) на этапе `msg_2` с соответствующими `callback_data`, например "*точка_А*" и "*точка_В*". Затем проверяйте входящие объекты `Update` на соответствие типу [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) и если это он - то смотрите содержимое поля `data`, так и определите какая кнопка была нажата и какую именно точку выбрал пользователь.

Comment: А как на этапе `msg_6` бот может получить `callback_data` с этапа `msg_3`?

Comment: @Tarasovich почему на этапе `msg_6`? Получили `callback_data` - переходите к шагу `msg_4`

Comment: насколько я понял, после проверки `callback_data` можно только лишь вывести оповещение методом [`answerCallbackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery), вот что я пытался сделать: https://pastebin.com/x7c6XJ1z

Comment: @Tarasovych странно, что эта логика не работает у вас. Или разобрались уже?

Comment: не разобрался( После `InlineKeyboardMarkup` удалось вызвать только `answerCallbackQuery`

Comment: @Tarasovych тогда покажите весь код (желательно с комментариями). И ещё, какую-то библиотеку используете для работы с апи или сами обёртку писали?